# How Fix issue of Exoplayer with playinp H.264 format video

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediaplayer, h.264, exoplayer

I have a device with android 4.2.2 running on it and created an app that uses the latest version of **ExoPlayer** as it's video player component. my player was working great on playing videos using ProgressiveMediaSource. but yesterday I found out that it has trouble with playing an **H.264 format video**. the video was playing but it just showed a **gray screen**.

I dug deeper and realized that the only difference between this video and the earlier videos was that they have different **profile** specifications (working videos were **Main** and that video was **High**).

First, I guessed that maybe it's **codec** is not supporting but I created an app with **[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)** and it played it with no issue.

This may seem a duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073827/mpeg-ts-h-264-with-exoplayer) but It did not help me.

I read the whole [troubleshooting page of ExoPlayer docs](https://exoplayer.dev/troubleshooting.html), especially those related to my file type (MP4) but it did not seem to be related to my issue.

And the last thing that I tried was adding **analytics** to my ExoPlayer but did not see any log like this:

```
[ ] Track:x, id=x, mimeType=mime/type, ... , supported=NO_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE
```

I know that my knowledge about this issue is not vast and I need to improve it in order to fix the issue and any direct or indirect advice would be greatly appreciated.

PS. You can see my video files [here](https://gofile.io/?c=nkgb5Q). I added three working videos and that special corrupted one, there. all video files have standard formatting, bitrate, profile, and encoding.

Comment: Can you share videos?

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 I added some video files for your request. one of them is named corrupted and that is the video file that I'm talking about.

Comment: Did you play these videos with exoplayer demo application?
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 Yes, but no, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried your video on my example of [exoplayer-kotlin](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin). It didn't work and got the same issue.

I went to check the github repo and found this [exoplayer issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6656). It seems to be a bug that the library doesn't intend to solve. You either have to do some process on your video, or use another video component if this is vital for you application.

EDIT: I've taken the sample that [official-exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) is offering and add in the `media.exolist.json` this:

```
"name": "Widevine DASH: MP4,H264",
"samples": [
  {
    "name": "TEST: CORRUPTED",
    "uri": "https://YOUR-IP/corrupted.mp4"
  },
...
```

in the log I got this :

```java
tracks [eventTime=0.21, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, 
  Renderer:0 [
    Group:0, adaptive_supported=N/A [
      [X] Track:0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, res=1280x800, fps=29.970032, supported=YES
    ]
  ]
]
```

However the video stutter a lot and is not viewable.

Comment: Thanks, but the option of changing video format is not possible because my boss knows that it plays with MediaPlayer and expects from me to solve the issue, no matter what.

The issue you're referring to is saying that it is not ExoPlayer related issue. do  I need to open an issue?

Comment: You should open an issue and try to look with them where it is coming from. You can also look in the [old issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues?q=is%3Aissue+NO_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE) if someone has the same behaviour than you.